# Is there a way to pass arguments to a query in CodeIgniter *without* using ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, database, codeigniter, arguments

This is what I'd like to do, but it doesn't seem possible:
(edit: changed single to double quotes)

```
function get_archives($limit, $offset) 
{
    $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT  archivalie.id, 
                archivalie.signature, 
                type_of_source.description AS type_of_source_description, 
                media_type.description AS media_type_description,
                origin.description AS origin_description

        FROM    archivalie, 
                type_of_source, 
                media_type,
                origin

        WHERE   archivalie.type_of_source_id = type_of_source.id                                                        
        AND     type_of_source.media_type_id = media_type.id  
        AND     archivalie.origin_id = origin.id                                                                     

        ORDER BY    archivalie.id ASC
        LIMIT       $limit, $offset
    "); 


    // etc...

}
```

It gives this error:
(edit: new error message using double quotes, and with an offset number passed in the URL)

```
ERROR: LIMIT #,# syntax is not supported HINT: Use separate LIMIT and OFFSET clauses.
```

It only works if you pass the variables using the ActiveRecord format:

```
$this->db->select('archivalie.id, archivalie.signature, etc, etc');
// from, where, etc.
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);        
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = $this->db->query('
SELECT  archivalie.id, 
        archivalie.signature, 
        type_of_source.description AS type_of_source_description, 
        media_type.description AS media_type_description,
        origin.description AS origin_description
FROM    archivalie, 
        type_of_source, 
        media_type,
        origin
WHERE   archivalie.type_of_source_id = type_of_source.id                                                        
AND     type_of_source.media_type_id = media_type.id  
AND     archivalie.origin_id = origin.id                                                                     
ORDER BY    archivalie.id ASC
LIMIT       ?
OFFSET      ?',array($limit,$offset));
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
$query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT  archivalie.id, 
            archivalie.signature, 
            type_of_source.description AS type_of_source_description, 
            media_type.description AS media_type_description,
            origin.description AS origin_description

    FROM    archivalie, 
            type_of_source, 
            media_type,
            origin

    WHERE   archivalie.type_of_source_id = type_of_source.id                                                        
    AND     type_of_source.media_type_id = media_type.id  
    AND     archivalie.origin_id = origin.id                                                                     

    ORDER BY    archivalie.id ASC
    LIMIT       $limit
    OFFSET      $offset
");
```

But it requires a check to assign a default value if no offset is present in the URL. From my controller:

```
# Check/assign an offset
$offset = (!$this->uri->segment(3)) ? 0 : $this->uri->segment(3);

# Get the data
$archives = $this->archive->get_archives($config['per_page'], $offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the data type of the parameter.  If you don't want Codeigniter to add the `'' single quotes, make sure you are passing an integer.

```
$page = '10'; // for some reason this arrives as a string
$sql = "select * from customers limit 10 offset ?";
$result = $this->db->query($sql, array(intval($page));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you used double quotes instead of single quotes it would work, but you'd be open to an injection attack if the variables weren't sanitized properly.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but why would single versus double quotes make a difference to SQL injection attacks?

Comment: I'm with Thomas. I don't get what Greg means with this.

Comment: Because you're passing a variable directly into an SQL statement - you should escape it first.

Comment: Question was changed after I answered btw